# Adding Audio To If Statement

Tags: javascript

Im using java script for a simple if else statement and was trying to add some audio to it.  Play one song when its right, and another if its bad.  Here is what I have minus the actual if statements.  I commented out the audio portion because that broke my code and couldn't get it working.

```
if (x is true)
      {
    document.write("Good job!<br />");

        /*<audio controls = "controls" autoplay = "autoplay" loop ="loop" >
        <source src = "congrats.ogg" type = "audio/ogg" />
        <source src = "congrats.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg" />
        <source src = "congrats.wav" type = "audio/wav" />
        Your browser does not support the audio element
        </audio>*/
      }
else
      {
    document.write("Boo!<br />");
      }
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Update for clarification:** I was trying to say that if my "if statement" executes, play song1 and if my "else statement" executes, play song2.

**Update, working!:**  Did some more research and was able to find the following snippet of code that works for me.

http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/introduction-to-the-html5-audio-tag-javascript-manipulation/

Comment: You can't just stick HTML in the middle of Javascript like that. You have to use something like `getElementById('audiodiv').innerHTML='<audio ...><source ...> ... </audio>';`

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply.  I am not too familiar with the getElementById() method, will have to look into it more.  After I posted my above code, I tried doing a `document.write();` and putting it in there but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript, you can do something like this:

```
var supports = function(mime) { return (new Audio()).canPlayType('audio/' + mime); };
var sound;

if (supports('ogg; codecs=vorbis')) {
    sound = new Audio('congrats.ogg');
} else if (supports('mpeg')) {
    sound = new Audio('congrats.mp3');
} else if (supports('wav')) {
    sound = new Audio('congrats.wav');
} else {
  alert('Your browser is horrible');
}

if (typeof sound !== 'undefined') {
    sound.play();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that is not quite what I was looking for.  I was trying to say that if my "if statement" executes, play song1 and if my "else statement" executes, play song2.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really have `if (x is true)`?

That should be just `if (x)`

Comment: That's not an answer to his question. He said "minus the actual if statements" -- that part is obviously pseudocode.